# c++ run time checking

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

A major problem when building Release   version is  using uninitialized variables.using a variable that in debug version is never initialized but  it default value is  zero and in Release version get a  random value and application  crashes. VS2010 warn about uninitialized  local variables but not about uninitialized member variables. there is another option to set basic run time checking /RTCSU and debug in to code when using uninitialized member. it is  great!. but when I use  static library it doesn't work! !I set both Basic Run Time  Checks to /BOTH.i want to know  is it operational to use this option on a large project to check uninitialized member variable?

Comment: Careful coding is the answer to uninitialized variables. Particularly member variables, just initialize them in the constructor(s).

Comment: yes. but we work  with a large software that uses some open sources which some of them didn't work properly in release mode.also I think run time checking mus not be very difficult I wonder why VS2010 does no support it with member variable?